# Wordpress plugin for independent self-hosted CDN

Tags: cookies, wordpress, subdomain, cdn

I'm trying to set a cookieless subdomain to serve static content of my wordpress website. So I've tried ***self-hosted CDN solutions*** using WP SuperCache or W3 Total Cache plugin.

My wordpress is on the domain ***aljazair24.com*** and my CDN domain is ***static1.aljazair24.com***. The domain and subdomain point to the ***same apache directory*** (/home/username/public_html).

Although WP SuperCache and W3TC plugins allow to set cookie domain to aljazair24.com, the subdomain static1.aljazair24.com still sends cookies to browsers...

I've tried to set cookie domain to www.aljazair24.com in order to avoid this but it doesn't work, since all ***www urls are redirected to non-www*** ones...

I was desperately looking for any WP plugin allowing to make "real" mirror resources, all this in order to avoid any interference at htaccess level. Unfortunately I didn't find anything ...

What should I do to make subdomain ***static1.aljazair24.com*** cookie-free ?

Page speed tests using **YSlow**

```
Grade F on Use cookie-free domains
  There are 82 components that are not cookie-free

  http://static1.aljazair24.com/wp-content/plugins/ajax-load-more/core/js/ajax-load-more.min.js
  http://static1.aljazair24.com/wp-content/themes/aljazair/inc/js/flexslider.min.js
  http://static1.aljazair24.com/wp-content/plugins/wysija-newsletters/js/validate/languages/jquery.validationEngine-ar.js
  http://static1.aljazair24.com/wp-content/plugins/wysija-newsletters/js/front-subscribers.js
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cloudflare? Most hosting providers have a built in extension and you dont have go through plugins like WP SuperCache or W3 Total Cache.